# MULTIPOINT Text to list of POINT objects

Tags: shapely, point-in-polygon, multipoint

I need to convert a MULTIPOINT string to a list of POINT objects. For example, suppose I have a query with `ST_AsText()` producing an output that is captured in `my_points`:

```
>>>print(my_points)
result={str}'MULTIPOINT(-1.0 1.2, 3.4 5.6, 7.8 9.0)'
```

I need `result` to be converted to a list of POINT objects so that I can use `STRtree()` to query if the points intersect a polygon.

I have tried the following:

```
[x.split(' ') for x in result[11:-1].split(',')]
```

but it only returns a list of strings:

```
(['-1.0', '1.2'], ['3.4', '4.5']...)
```

I need each element in each list to be floats so that I can convert them to Points.

What is the most efficient way to convert the MULTIPOINT string to an actual list of Points?

I am a novice to GIS *and* Python, not to programming in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `my_points` is a Multipoint object, you can iterate over each individual point of the multipoint as you can iterate over a list and access each point's geometry. The following line will create a list of tuples, one for each point with their respective x and y coordinates.

```
individual_points = [(pt.x, pt.y) for pt in my_points]
print(individual_points)  # [(-1.0, 1.2), (3.4, 5.6), (7.8, 9.0)]
```

For more information see the [Collections Shapely documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#collections)

Comment: The dilemma stems from the fact that `my_points` is *not* a MultiPoint object, but a string; however, your response did point me in the right direction to resolve the issue:

`[Point(x.split(' ')[0], x.split(' ')[1]) for x in result[11:-1].split(',')]`